# apa-style biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

i'm using italian language and apa-style.
I need to insert the date in the bibliography in the format e.g. 17 Aprile 2020,
as is the case for the French language, I don't understand what file I need to edit and how.
thank you

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I'm a bit confused about what you want. Your document uses English and Italian. Where do you need a French date? In a specific `.bib` item? Which sorts of entries should have dates formatted this way? Can you provide an example `.bib` item, and make your example compilable?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I don't have to use the French language, but I wanted the result of the bibliography in the style as if I entered the French language.
In Italian it looks like this:
Benedetti, A. (2018). I nomi delle vacche di Vallo di Nera. [Online]. Recuperato settembre 13, 2019,
While in French it is like this:
Benedetti, A. (2018). I nomi delle vacche di Vallo di Nera. [Online]. Récupérée 13 septembre 2019

note that in French the date format is: 13 septembre 2019

Comment: Ok, thanks that's much clearer. Can you edit your question to show the `.bib` file entry (not the formatted item) as well, and make your sample code compilable. This makes it easier for people to help you.